# Express-validator not breaking on right chain

Tags: node.js, error-handling, express-validator

I am using **express-validator** in nodejs. The code is always throwing first error message as a validation result.

**validation.js**

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const {handleError, ErrorHandler} = require('../helper/error');

const resultsOfValidation = (req,res,next) => {
  const messages = []; 
  const errors = validationResult(req); 
  if(errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next(); //pass to controller
  }
  errors.array().map( err => messages.push(err.msg));   
  throw new ErrorHandler(400,messages);
} 

const createUserValidator = () => {
     return [
        check('firstName')
            .exists({ checkFalsy: true }).withMessage('First Name is mandatory')
            .bail()
            .isAlpha().withMessage('First Name should have all alphabets') 
            .bail()
            .isLength({min:3}).withMessage('First Name should have minimum 3 characters')
        ,
        check('lastName')
            .optional({ checkFalsy: true }) //ignore validation when null or empty
            .isAlpha()
            .bail()            
     ]
  }    
   

module.exports = {
      resultsOfValidation,
      createUserValidator,          
 }
```

**user route** is below :

```
const router = express.Router();    
router
    .get('/',getAllUsers)
    .post('/',createUserValidator(),resultsOfValidation,(req,res) => console.log('created'))
    .get('/:id',getUserById)
    .delete('/',deleteUserById)

module.exports = router;
```

My **user.js controller** file is:

```
module.exports = {
  getAllUsers: async (req,res)=> {},
  createUser: async (req,res,next)=> {
    try{
        const errors = resultsOfValidation(req);
        if (errors.length >0) {                               
            throw new ErrorHandler(400, errors)
        }
        const { firstName, lastName } = req.body;
        // call createUser from model
        const user = await UserModel.createUser(firstName, lastName);
        if(!user) {
            throw new ErrorHandler(404, 'User not created')
        }
       // return res.status(200).json({ success: true, user });
      } catch (error) {          
        return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: error })
      }
  },
  getUserById: async (req,res)=> {},
  deleteUserById: async (req,res)=> {},   
}
```

Here is example of post request I made. It should throw *First Name should have minimum 3 characters*. But I am getting other error *First Name is mandatory*
[image: Postman request]

Comment: I do not use Postman that much, but from your screen grab, it seems the content-type header of your request is going to be set to "text/plain" - and not the "application/json" I understand you expect. In postman, use the dropdown in the body section to select JSON instead of Text.

Comment: Thanks, @IAmDranged. Got your point. I was sending objects as text so firstName was not recognized as the field name. I am now getting other error. typeError next is not a function.

Comment: I don't see such a misuse on next-) in your pasted code. I assume resultsOfValidation() now ends up throwing, so the next error middleware in line should get called. Does that sound right? Do you actually have such an error middleware set up? If so please paste your code.

Comment: You are right, I had mistakenly added () in calling second middleware resultsOfValidation() while troubleshooting. Now its working.

If you post as answer I can mark as an answer to the question as it is resolved now.